# How can I do this symbol (integral with a barre) in latex?

Tags: symbols

How can I do this symbole in latex ? (if possible with the barre of the middle more straight).

[image]

Comment: @Zarko: Could you tell me in what is duplicate ?

Comment: that similar question was already asked and answered. see given link, it answer there is helpful to you. if not you should specify what is specific/different in your case

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some fonts have such an integral sign built in, but if not, you can always stack a `-` or `$-$` over one.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
$\stackinset{c}{}{c}{}{\mkern1.5mu\mbox{-}}{\int}x\,dx$
$\displaystyle\stackinset{c}{}{c}{}{-\mkern4mu}{\displaystyle\int_0^t}x\,dx$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Built in examples include versions with a slanted bar (denoted `\fint`) as well as some versions with a horizontal bar.

Those packages with a slanted `\fint` include: `txfonts`, `pxfonts`, `esint`, and `stix`.

Versions with a horizontal bar include:

1. `\strokedint` from the `MnSymbol` package, and
2. `\intbar` from the `stix` package.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Yes I know they are slanted, similar to the OP's graphic.  I will note that in my answer.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks, I have edited my answer to reflect this new info.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I had explicitly mention at the end of my answer that the various `\fint` macros have a slanted bar.  Need I do more, in your opinion?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65909/discussion-between-barbara-beeton-and-steven-b-segletes).

Answer (score 8):

The symbol already exists in `esint`:

```
\documentclass[ a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{esint}

\newcommand*{\dd}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\begin{document}

\[ \fint_{\partial\mathrlap{B_{R}}}u(y)\dd y \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like your definition of `\dd`! (+1).

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher: Thank you for your kind appreciation! Actually, credit is not mine: if I remember well, I borrowed it from an answer of egreg on this site.